# Change MuiDataGrid toolbarContainer buttons style for light theme

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

Can someone explain to me how to get to these buttons in the DataGrid?

[image]

I want to change the color which atm. looks like this although they are not disabled.

[image]

How am I supposed to select the classes correctly to get to the buttons? I actually fixed this by just styling with the `sx` prop

```
sx={{
  '& .MuiDataGrid-toolbarContainer': {
   '& .MuiButton-text': {
    color: '#074682',
    },
  },
}}
```

[image]

But I would like to do this in my theme (components) for light mode here

[image]

I read the css documentation of [DataGrid](https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/data-grid/) on Mui and I'm confused about how to get deeper into `toolbarContainer`.

Any help is appreciated. I really want to understand this and not just try out stuff.

I can see:

- MuiDataGrid-root
- MuiDataGrid-toolbarContainer
  THEN
- MuiButton-text

Would I then just select them in that order?

EDIT:
This also works:

[image]

But why can't I just select the `MuiButton`, then the `text` and then add the color like this:

[image]